# Paypal Adaptive Chained Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I am super confused on what this documentation is trying to say.(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APCallsHeadersAndPaymentTypes/)

Basically, I am trying to facilitate payments between 2 users. I also want to have a fee paid to me during this transaction. The confusing part of the documentation are the headers.

According to the reference you need these.

```
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", "tok261_biz_api.abc.com");
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD","123456");
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE","Signature"
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", "APP-APPID");
```

I don't know what to put for X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID or X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD. I do not want to put my actual username and password. Is this what I am supposed to be doing to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are your API credentials.  You obtain those values in your PayPal profile under API Access, then choose the signature method.

Alternatively, you can [click this link](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) and login with your PayPal account to quickly obtain those values.

Comment: Is it common practice to save those values that page generates on my server so I can continue to make calls from that?

Comment: Yes, you would save the credentials in a config file and include that config file that you include with your project files making the API calls.